# i2c to i2c bridge (router)?

Tags: i2c

I'm currently working on a project where something as silly as a i2c to i2c bridge would be perfect. Unfortunately they don't seem to exist. Anyone know of one? Is there any reason why they don't exist besides no one sees the need?

Let me explain the project. I'm making a module Video switch that can have modules for different input types (RGB, Component, HDMI, etc). Each module will stack with a Microcontroller module being able to control everything in the stack. It would be nice if I would only have to use 2 lines in the board interconnects to control all the boards (i2c). The issue is multiple of the same board can be used in the stack so there would be identical i2c chips on the same bus. Sure I could use DIP switches for each IC to address each on but that make design and software development a nightmare. So it would be nice if I could address a i2c slave on each board (1 DIP switch for each board) and then command that slave to be the master of a i2c chips on that board.

One thought is to use a i2c to SPI connected to a SPI to i2c (Not sure if that would work). Any thoughts on all this rambling? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I²C muxes exist. You would need one such 2->1-mux on each board, either connecting the board or the far end to the host end of the bus. That way the host can address each board in the stack individually by switching the concatenated muxes in the way.

Comment: That just might work. I was tinkering with Muxes to think of a way they could do the job but could think of one. Essentially what you are saying is use a mux to only connect 1 board to the bus at a time. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a 1:1 switch for the I2C bus, or for a 1:many multiplexer (mux)?  Are the modules going to be hot-pluggable?  By the way, a block diagram could help your questions a lot.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is probably an *I2C multiplexer*. There is a wide selection of these parts available, but one example is TI's [TCA9544A](http://www.ti.com/product/tca9544a/datasheet). It's effectively a 1-to-4 switch for I2C signals, which will itself respond to I2C commands at a configurable address. Unlike a normal switch, though, each of the four downstream channels can be switched on or off separately -- so it's possible to enable more than one of those channels at a time, if appropriate, or even to disable them all.

Another option is an *I2C address translator*. These are less common; one example is Linear's [LTC4317](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4317). This device can be used to effectively change the address of an I2C device behind the translator.

Comment: The TCA9544A is a great solution but unfortunately will only run up to 400 kHz. If you already have a microprocessor capable of byte wide I/O you could use the new NXP PCA9663 (http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCA9663.pdf). I have not tried it but the datasheet says it supports through to FM and gives you 3 independent I2C channels, If you already have an I2C on the microcontroller that would give you 4 completely independent channels to work with.

Comment: @JackCreasey There are probably plenty of faster I2C muxes available, too -- the TCA9544A is literally just the first one I found listed on TI's site.

Answer (score 0):

The I2C requires specific timing. That 'router' should be almost invisible to make all the timing work. There are chips for level shifting and even a on-the-fly translater: [Hackaday about LTC4316](http://hackaday.com/2017/02/17/ltc4316-is-the-i2c-babelfish/). But that is enough problems already, there is no router.

It is possible to have a Arduino Uno with its hardware I2C to act as a Slave and a software I2C to act as a Master. I'm not sure if I understand your question. It will require a lot of programming and it needs a good protocol, it will not be easy to implement, and I don't know how reliable it will be. Some microcontrollers have two I2C busses. For example the ATmega328PB, it has two I2C busses, and a unique ID in every chip.

Comment: Right now going with a microcontroller might be the only solution but kind of what I was trying to avoid is each board would be a "dumb board" which wouldn't have any kind of programming of firmware on it. Only the main board would have a microcontroller and would control all the dumb boards.

Pretty much what I am describing is something like a SPI to i2c bridge but took commands from i2c instead of SPI. They have their own clocks in them to handle timing and everything.

Comment: The first statement is wrong -- I2C is a completely synchronous protocol, and has no specific timing requirements at all. You can run it as slow as you like, as long as there's enough bandwidth to transfer all of the required data.

Comment: @DaveTweed I should have been more specific. There is no specific timing to do I2C. But, for example, the timing and delays between SDA and SCL is very specific. When only one signal would slow down, it might no longer work. I'm still a little confused with the term 'router'. It can be either a mux or a microcontroller. As far as I know, there is no intelligent 'router' off the shell for I2C.